# sed replace text with backslash \ and curved brackets {} using bash variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a line of latex source code which I want to replace.
The problem is, it contains **curved brackets** and **backslash**.
Furthermore, I would like to replace it with a **bash variable**

**Before**: In `case0.tex`, I have this line:

```
\title{Analysis Case 0}
```

I want to change the title inside the curved bracket to a string contained in a bash variable called `$CASE`.
This is what I tried, however I am not sure how to treat this special case with `sed`.

```bash
CASE=Analysis Case 1
sed -e "s/ \title{Analysis Case 0} / \title{ $CASE } /g" ./case0.tex > ./case1.tex
```

**After**: In `case1.tex` I would like to get this line.

```
\title{Analysis Case 1}
```

It would be nice if someone could tell me how to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ case="Analysis Case 1"
$ sed s"/\({\)[^}]*/\1$case/" case0.tex > case1.tex
$ cat case1.tex
\title{Analysis Case 1}
```

Comment: I managed to change only the title using `sed s"/\(title{\)[^}]*/\1$snap/" case0.tex > case1.tex`. However when I want to change the` \subtitle`, not the title, how do I do that. This is a texfile so there are more of the curved brackets

Comment: @Kazuma Can you provide an example?